# What does the behavior of elements of $\mathcal{O}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))$ tell us about their behavior as elements of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

I just finished a section of a course that touched on the spectra $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ of commutative rings $R$, first as sets, then as topological spaces, and finally as locally ringed spaces. (I understand that elsewhere this is called the structure sheaf on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$).

While trying to do an exercise about the bijection between nontrivial nilpotent elements of $R$ and clopen sets of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ (really about showing the equivalency of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ being disconnected, $R$ having orthogonal idempotents, and $R$ being isomorphic to a nontrivial product ring) I found a lot of answers on here and elsewhere that essentially proceeded by taking $\mathrm{Spec}(R) = V(\mathfrak{a}) \sqcup V(\mathfrak{b})$, defining an element $f \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ through gluing by $f \restriction_{V(\mathfrak{a})} \equiv 1$, $f \restriction_{V(\mathfrak{b})} \equiv 0$ and then using the isomorphism $\mathrm{Spec}(R) \cong R$ to say that $f$ was our nontrivial idempotent.

Intuitively, it makes sense to me that, given that you can use a nontrivial idempotent to decompose $R$ as a product ring, $f$ would "act like 1" on $V(\mathfrak{a})$ and "act like 0" on $V(\mathfrak{b})$, but I do not actually understand how we can tell that $f$ is idempotent.

From what I understand about the definition of the structure ring, what we know about $f$ as an element of $R$ is this:

For any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \supseteq \mathfrak{a}$, $\frac{f}{1} = \frac{1}{s}$ for $s \notin \mathfrak{p}$, which is equivalent to the existence of $r \in R$ such that $r ( f s - 1 ) = 0$. Also, for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \supseteq \mathfrak{b}$, $\frac{f}{1} = \frac{0}{s}$ for $s \notin \mathfrak{q}$, which is equivalent to the existence of $r \in R$ such that $r f s = 0$.

Is there any way to get from these facts or similar to $f$ being idempotent? Was my intuition valid? I didn't quite understand the solutions given that used this strategy, and a lot of them seemed to assume the thing I was trying to prove.

More broadly, this strategy of "gluing together" a desired element of a ring by describing the behavior of the corresponding element of $\mathcal{O}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))$ restricted to different subsets seems really useful, but I don't see how you can actually use it if all you know about the element you have constructed are the facts above.

(To be clear I eventually found a more elementary strategy for that exercise. I'm not just asking for a proof that $f$ is idempotent, I want to know if my intuition here was valid.)

Comment: I think you mean "idempotent", not "nilpotent".

Comment: If $\mathfrak{p} \in V(\mathfrak{a})$, then $f = 1$ in $R_\mathfrak{p}$. In this ring, $1 = \frac 11$, not $1 = \frac 1s$ for all $s \notin \mathfrak{p}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean *idempotent* when you wrote *nilpotent*.

If $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{V}(\mathfrak{a})$, then $\frac{f^2 - f}1 = \left(\frac f1\right)^2 - \frac f1 = 1^2 - 1 = 0$ in $R_\mathfrak{p}$. If $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{V}(\mathfrak{b})$, then $\frac{f^2 - f}1 = \left(\frac f1\right)^2 - \frac f1 = 0^2 - 0 = 0$ in $R_\mathfrak{p}$. In both cases we obtain $s \in R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ such that $s(f^2 - f) = 0$ in $R$.

Let $\mathfrak{n} = \{g \in R : g(f^2 - f) = 0\}$ be the annihilator of $(f^2 - f)$. This is an ideal. The previous paragraph shows that for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ there is an element $s \in \mathfrak{n} \setminus \mathfrak{p}$. In particular, $\mathfrak{n}$ is not contained in any prime ideal. Since any ideal $\neq (1)$ is contained in a maximal ideal, this is only possible for $\mathfrak{n} = (1)$.

Now $1$ is contained in the annihilator, so $f^2 - f = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! That's surprisingly straightforward! (I've submitted an edit to change \mathfrak{a} to \mathfrak{n} just to avoid overloading \mathfrak{a}.